# What is the expected area of this enclosure?

Tags: probability-distributions

I have no clue how to do this textbook question:
An environmental artist is planning to construct a rectangle with 36m of fencing as part of an outdoor installation. If the length of the rectangle is a randomly chosen integral number of $L$ metres, what is the expected area of this enclosure?

Comment: I'm guessing the possible side lengths are all equally likely? Also, is the rectangle with dimensions $18 \times 0$ allowed?

Answer (score 2):

Let $L$ denote the length of the rectangle, and $W$ the width.

We know that $2L+2W=36$, so $L+W=18$, i.e. $W=18-L$.  The rectangle's area is $A=LW=L(18-L)$.

Since $L$ is known to be an integer, and $W,L$ must both be nonnegative, then $L$ is chosen from $$\{0,1,2,3,\ldots, 18\}$$

Now, computed the expected value of $A$, as $L$ varies among its possible values.  Do you need help with this part?

---

Adding more details per request.  The desired value is $$\sum_{L}APr(A)=\sum_L L(18-L)\frac{1}{19}=\frac{1}{19}\sum_{L=0}^{18} 18L - L^2=$$
$$=\frac{18}{19}\sum_{L=0}^{18}L - \frac{1}{19}\sum_{L=0}^{18}L^2$$

These last sums can be computed using [Faulhaber's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Examples).

Comment: I understand what you have written, but do I use a binomial distribution now? If so, how do I apply it?

Comment: Do you know how to calculate $E(L^2)$? Either in principle, or actually doing it by hand?

Comment: @ConMan Unfortunately, I do not.

Comment: The distribution of $L$ is not stated in the question, but it seems fair to assume that each possible value of $L$ is equally likely (so $P(L) = 1/19$ for each possible $L$ if $L$ can be any value in $\{0,\ldots,18\}$).

For computing the expected value you can just apply the definition directly.

Comment: Great answer (+1).  It is also useful to point out that an $18 \times 0$ "rectangle" might not be considered a genuine rectangle, and might therefore be counted out of consideration.  Under that interpretation, the expected area will be $19 / 17$ times the above calculation.